# How to get jqBootstrapValidation form example to work?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, client-side

I tried to follow the instructions at the [jqBootstrapValidation](http://reactiveraven.github.io/jqBootstrapValidation/) site but couldn't get a simple example to work. I chose the email validation. Not sure what could be wrong, but I am suspecting that it might be step 2 of the installation instructions, which I included at the bottom of the example below.

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
<div class="control-group">
<label class="control-label">Email address</label>
<div class="controls">
<input type="email" />
<p class="help-block"></p>
</div>
</div>
</form>

<!--Scripts-->
<script>
   $(function () { $("input,select,textarea").not("[type=submit]").jqBootstrapValidation(); } );
</script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script> <!-- or use local jquery -->     
<script src="./js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

you are not including the jqBootstrapValidation.js..

[download](https://github.com/ReactiveRaven/jqBootstrapValidation/zipball/1.3.6) and include this line at the bottom:

```
<script src="./js/jqBootstrapValidation.js"></script>
```

after or before:

```
<script src="./js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

but not above where you call jQuery:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

other wise it will not work as jqBootstrapValidation needs jQuery to work

Answer (score 1):

I think this simple example will help you..

```
</head>
<body>
    <!------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
    <form class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Email address</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="email" />
                <p class="help-block"></p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Type something</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" name="some_field" required />
                <p class="help-block"></p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Type a number</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="number" />
                <p class="help-block"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="enter1"/>
    </form>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script> <!-- or use local jquery -->
    <script src="/js/jqBootstrapValidation.js"></script>
    <script>

        $(function() {
            $("input,select,textarea").not("[type=submit]").jqBootstrapValidation();
        });

    </script>
    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
```